# I accidentally deleted the bcd file for Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

As the title says, I deleted the bcd boot loader for Windows 10 by mistake using `Easy BCD`, and when I tried to restart the PC it could not boot and got the error.

**Note** I have access to grub2 Linux command line as I had a USB media to install Linux (which I tried to install it but didn't succeeded with it) and I don't have any other device to create USB media for Windows 10.

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you have any Linux available, either installed or liveUSB?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since this is a Q&A site, your post should contain a question. For now it's just a story. I *guess* you want to fix the issue, so the question probably is "how can I make my Windows bootable again?". But it may be "what makes `bcd` so important?". Why should we guess? Consider [edit]ing and asking an explicit question.

Comment: I have Linux installed but I can't boot it, it takes me to grub command line and when I enter to recover mode for Linux it show me command line to login asking the username and password which I have neither since I installed Linux from secure mode

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever created a recovery disk for the computer,
now is the time to use it.

If you haven't, then you absolutely need a Windows 10
installation media.
Perhaps a friend could help you in creating one.

When you have the boot media, you need to boot into the
Command Prompt in order to issue the command:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Rebuild the BCD in Windows](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508).

Comment: I have neither, I moved to a new country and I am new there so no friends available, lol

Comment: Ask a colleague or someone. Doing any hacking could make it worse.

Comment: @HaDiAyOuB - Download an ISO for the same version of Windows you have installed.  This cannot be solved without running that command. This is the correct and only answer to your question

Comment: I managed to have a Windows 10 media and booted to command prompt and tried `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, it prompted me the following: `Ttoal identified Windows installations :1... [1] C:\Windows.. Add installation to boot list? Yrs(Y) /No(N)/All(A) :` I typed Yes and I got **The requested system device cannot be found.** error